# Easiest way to download a file?

Tags: file, http, go

I can do something like below, which gives me a response class, but I'm not exactly sure how to write the io.reader to a file. What is the most straightforward way?

```
http.Get("https://www.domain.com/some.jpg")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the file is small enough the easiest solution is to use [ioutil.WriteFile](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile) combined with [ioutil.ReadAll](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)  :

```
resp, err := http.Get("your url")
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, bytes, 0666)
```

If your file isn't so small, you'd better avoid creating and filling the `bytes` array. Then you should  use [io.Copy](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) which simply copies the bytes from the reader to the writer :

```
resp, err := http.Get("your url")
f, err := os.Create(filename)
defer f.Close()
_, err := io.Copy(f, resp.Body)
```

You must add the relevant error handling in both cases.

Comment: I'd really want to deemphasize `ioutil.ReadAll` -- it's almost never what you want to do in a well-behaved application.

Comment: @Dustin If the file is small enough, I think it doesn't matter. Do you think I should put more emphasis on this point ?

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but perhaps the io.Copy version should be first.  I think your code and reasoning are both right (though I could do something nasty to your program).  I'm just afraid I'll see more people doing the "pull everything into memory" thing.

Comment: @Dustin It's a legitimate concern. But with the Go1.1 GC and all the involved layers, it's not such a big problem. I just did some benchmarks. On a big (4MB) file, `io.Copy` is much faster (about twice in my tests, I guess it could be more different in a memory constrained environment). On a small or medium file (<5kB), both functions take about the same time (Copy is faster by about 10% to 15%).

Comment: 4MB is not big. 700 MB is big. Well, the real problem is that if you download from the web you can not really be sure how big the file is that is sent to you. You may expect it to be a certain size, but the other end could still send you more (garbage).

Comment: 4MB is big enough to start to look for another solution than the "easiest one" (which was the question). That's why I added a second solution (io.copy).

Answer (score 0):

`ReadFrom` is useful in some cases:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("http://speedtest.lax.hivelocity.net")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   f, e := os.Create("index.html")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.ReadFrom